# How to filter a SQL Server table with another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, difference

Let's assume that we have two tables. In the first one, we store specific words:

```
id  word
1   apple
2   banana
3   orange
```

and in the second table, we have words that were entered by user

```
id  word
1   pear
2   apple
3   watermelon
4   cherry
5   strawberry
6   banana
```

Which SQL statement do I need to delete words from second table that are in first table and have this as a second table?

```
id  word
1   pear
3   watermelon
4   cherry
5   strawberry
```

Here is my code:

```
using (con)
{
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "delete from word where word.word in (select filter.word from filter)";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to actually delete the rows:

```
delete from t2
    where t2.word in (select t1.word from t1);
```

Comment: Or if you want to select unique words instead of actually deleting them, you may change it to `select * from t2 where t2.word not in (select t1.word from t1);`

Comment: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized. I got this error.Modified code, I have added in my first post.

Comment: @infoperto your issue isn't with the query, you aren't connecting to the database properly in the first place. That's a completely different question from what you've originally asked.